# error on data update with a d3pie.js piechart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3pie.js

I am trying to update a piechart from d3pie.js library however there must be something basic I am missing.

I have two scripts which look the same to me with the only difference being that the update happens via a button press whereas in the other happens on the fly, while the page loads up. I also got an error with the second script `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined`. I do get a chart, it is just the wrong one; Instead of 2 slices, get 3 (2 with the same color). The `pullOutSegment`event also doesnt work, so something is really messed-up with the piechart. The `pie` object looks to be different and maybe this is why the 2nd script fails but I have no idea to get the correct one. Its been doing my head since yesterday. The scripts are inluded below, the first one is the working code, the second the failed one.

Any help highly appreciated!

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<input type="button"; value="Add Data"; id="addData" />
<div id="pie"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3pie@0.2.1/d3pie/d3pie.min.js"></script>



<script>
function piechartData() {
    var data = [
        {label: "1", value: 1},
        {label: "2", value: 4},
        {label: "3", value: 3}
    ];

    var pie = new d3pie("pie", {
        data: {
            content: data
        }
    });

    return pie
};
</script>

<script>


    // create a piechart
    pie = piechartData();

    $(function() {

        //clear the data
        data = [];
        $("#addData").on("click", function() {

            //when button pressed push these and update the piechart
            data.push({"label": "4", "value": 8});
            data.push({"label": "51", "value": 3});;

            pie.updateProp("data.content", data);
        });
    });

</script>



</body>
</html>
```

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="pie"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src='https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/d3pie@0.2.1/d3pie/d3pie.min.js"></script>

<script>
    function piechartData() {
        var data = [
            {label: "1", value: 1},
            {label: "2", value: 4},
            {label: "3", value: 3}
        ];

        var pie = new d3pie("pie", {
            data: {
                content: data
            }
        });

        return pie
    };
</script>

<script>

    // make a piechart
    pie = piechartData();

    //create new data and update the piechart
    data = [];
    data.push({"label": "4", "value": 8});
    data.push({"label": "51", "value": 3});

    pie.updateProp("data.content", data);



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example clears the content of the svg (`updateProp`) but not all the transitions. They still live inside d3.

If you wait till the initial animation is finished

```
setTimeout(() => {
    data = [];
    data.push({"label": "4", "value": 8});
    data.push({"label": "51", "value": 3});

    pie.updateProp("data.content", data);
}, 5000);
```

It all works.

I don't know if there is an easy way to get a callback when d3pie is finished with all the animations.

Comment: Yes! you are right. Thats the problem. What I also figured  is that if you put the updateProp call inside a document ready statement, like         $(function() {
            pie.updateProp("data.content", data);
        }); then it seems to work.  Apparently the chart has to be finished before starting manipulating it. That wasnt clear to me. Still working on it though to see how I can use it. Many many thanks!!

Comment: @Aenaon: add a parameter to the `piechartData` and use that for data instead of defining the data inside the function, or replace the data with the argument if defined.